# table has invaded the margin of the document

Tags: tables

this is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htpb]
\centering
{
    \caption{\small{Descrição do Requisito Funcional $02$}} \vspace{10pt}
    \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p {6cm}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RF02: Exibir nome, DRE e situação de matrícula do aluno} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Objetivo: permitir que o usuário visualize nome, DRE e situação de matrícula do aluno} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Pré-condições: o usuário deve estar logado no sistema} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Pós-condições: o nome, o DRE e a situação de matrícula são exibidas} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Prioridade (1-5): 1 (alta)} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Trigger: o usuário seleciona o nome do aluno orientado na página principal do sistema desejando acessar suas informações} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{RNF específicos: segurança - o usuário deve estar logado no sistema} \\
        \hline
        Usuário & Sistema\\
        \hline
        $1.$ Acessa o sistema & $2.$ Solicita CPF e senha\\
        \hline
        $3.$ Informa CPF e senha & $4.$ Valida CPF e senha\\
        & [E1: CPF ou senha incorretos]\\
        \hline
        $5.$ Seleciona o nome do aluno orientado & $6.$ Exibe o nome completo do aluno, seu DRE e sua situação de matrícula\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{[Fluxo de Exceção E1: CPF ou senha incorretos]} \\
        \hline
        &$1.$ Exibe mensagem de erro\\  
        \hline
        &$2.$ Retorna ao passo $2$ do fluxo principal\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
    \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```

this is the output:
[image]

how can i fix this so i can see the full table?

Comment: Would you be willing to have long lines that occupy the full width be set in multiple lines, like a paragraph?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the table to remain narrower so as to fit the page

Comment: @Werner -- I've re-opened this question as I think it's not a (full) duplicate of the FAQ-like query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let me encourage you to peruse the query [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5001) and its associated answers in case you would like to familiarize yourself with a number of useful techniques related to keeping the width of the table from exceeding the width of the textblock.

Second, on to the main issue that's afflicting your two-column table. The overflow happens because even though you've defined the table to allow automatic line breaking in its individual columns, you then employ the `l` column type -- which does *not* allow for automatic line breaking -- for the header elements that span both of the underlying columns.

The fix? I suggest you replace the `l` column type with the `p` column type. The main remaining issue is to determine the usable width of the combined columns. Since the usable width of the underlying columns is `6cm` and the two columns are separated by 2 bands of whitespace (in the amount of `\tabcolsep` each) and a vertical rule (with width `\arrayrulewidth`), the *usable width* of the combined columns equals `12cm+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth`.

I would further like to recommend that you (a) allow for hanging indentation of the material in the subcolumns and (b) omit some of the horizontal rules, especially in what amounts to the table's header, in order to make the table more readable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} % or 'portuguese'?

\usepackage{ragged2e,microtype}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
% Define two new column types:
% (a) for full-width columns:
  \newcolumntype{L}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr12cm+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\relax} @{}}
% (b) for half-width columns:
  \newlength\mylen
  \settowidth\mylen{$4.$\space} % amount of hanging indentation
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent\mylen}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a less-cramped look

\centering
\caption{%\small % <-- why?
         Descrição do Requisito Funcional $02$} 

\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{@{} P{6cm} | P{6cm} @{}}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{RF02: Exibir nome, DRE e situação de matrícula do aluno} \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{Objetivo: permitir que o usuário visualize nome, DRE e situação de matrícula do aluno} \\
   %\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{Pré-condições: o usuário deve estar logado no sistema} \\
   %\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{Pós-condições: o nome, o DRE e a situação de matrícula são exibidas} \\
   %\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{Prioridade (1--5): 1 (alta)} \\
   %\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{Trigger: o usuário seleciona o nome do aluno orientado na página principal do sistema desejando acessar suas informações} \\
   %\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{L}{RNF específicos: segurança -- o usuário deve estar logado no sistema} \\[0.5ex]
   \hline
   Usuário & Sistema\\
   \hline
   $1.$ Acessa o sistema    
   & $2.$ Solicita CPF e senha\\
   %\hline
   $3.$ Informa CPF e senha 
   & $4.$ Valida CPF e senha\\
   & [E1: CPF ou senha incorretos]\\
   %\hline
   $5.$ Seleciona o nome do aluno orientado 
   & $6.$ Exibe o nome completo do aluno, seu DRE e sua situação de matrícula\\
   \hline
   &[Fluxo de Exceção E1: CPF ou senha incorretos] \\
   %\hline
   & $1.$ Exibe mensagem de erro\\  
   %\hline
   & $2.$ Retorna ao passo $2$ do fluxo principal\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you mean that the usable width is `12cm-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Because the usable width of the combined columns exceeds the simple sum of the underlying individual usable column widths (6cm each), one needs to *add*, not subtract, `2\tabcolsep` and `1\arrayrulewidth` to 12cm. :-)